# Version agnotstic checking if a variable is an integer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In python 2.6 and 2.7 you use

```
isinstance(variable, (int, long))
```

In python 3x [ints and longs are merged](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers). So you simply do

```
isinstance(variable, int)
```

Is there a clean version agnostic way of testing if a variable is an integer in python?

Comment: Good question, but I have to ask: Why does it matter? (I mean, why do you need to test if it is an integer?)

Comment: I'm interacting with a REST API. Before sending values I convert them from Python format to the expected format. True becomes "true', objects become their ids and integers become strings. So I need to figure out their type so I know how to format them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 2.6 you can use [numbers.Integral](http://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral):

```
if isinstance(var, numbers.Integral):
    pass # whatever
```